# How to write a code to timetravel using a specific transaction ID

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to use a timetravel feature on snowflake and restore the original table.

I've deleted and created the table using following command:

```
DROP TABLE "SOCIAL_LIVE"
CREATE  TABLE "SOCIAL_LIVE" (...)
```

I would like to go back to the original table before dropping table.

I've used following code (hid the transaction ID to 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')

```
Select "BW"."PUBLIC"."SOCIAL_LIVE".* From "BW"."PUBLIC"."SOCIAL_LIVE";
select * from SOCIAL_LIVE before(statement => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
```

Received an error message:

```
Statement xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx cannot be used to specify time for time travel query.
```

How can we go back to the original table and restore it on snowflake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation states:

> After dropping a table, creating a table with the same name creates a
>   new version of the table. The dropped version of the previous table
>   can still be restored using the following method:
>
> 1. Rename the current version of the table to a different name.
> 2. Use the UNDROP TABLE command to restore the previous version.

If you need further information, this page is useful:

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/drop-table.html#usage-notes

You will need to undrop the table in order to access that data, though.  Time-travel is not maintained by name alone.  So, once you dropped and recreated the table, the new table has its own, new time travel.

Answer (score 0):

Statement xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx cannot be used to specify time for time travel query.

Usually we will get above error when we trying to travel behind the object creation time. Try with time travel option with offset option.

Comment: The offset option is here: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-time-travel.html#time-travel-sql-extensions

Comment: Thank you!  After UNDROP the table, I could select the specific time using timestamp_LTZ, offset, and statement options.  I could not select the statement ID at DROP table query as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's 3 common reasons that error is seen, with solutions:

1. the table has been dropped and recreated

   - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58596178/6772415)
2. the time travel period has been exceeded

   - no solution: target a statement within the time travel period for the table
3. the wrong statement type is being targeted

   - only certain statement types can be targeted. Currently, these include `SELECT`, `BEGIN`, `COMMIT`, and DML (`INSERT`, `UPDATE` etc). [See documentation here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/at-before.html#syntax).